# How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtual-machine, 64bit, 32bit

I have a 64-bit (amd64 a.k.a. x86_64) Debian or Ubuntu installation. I need to run 32-bit (i386/i686) programs occasionally, or to compile programs for a 32-bit system. How can I do this with a minimum of fuss?

Bonus: what if I want to run or test with an older or newer release of the distribution?

Comment: Possible same on ask ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### For current releases

Current Debian and Ubuntu have multiarch support: You can mix x86_32 (i386) and x86_64 (amd64) packages on the same system in a straightforward way. This is known as multiarch support -
see [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) or [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) wiki more information.

See [warl0ck's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu/47003#47003) for a simple, up-to-date answer.

---

### For old releases

In older releases, Debian and Ubuntu ship with a number of 32-bit libraries on amd64. Install the [`ia32-libs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ia32-libs) [image: Install ia32-libs] package to have a basic set of 32-bit libraries, and possibly other packages that depend on this one. Your 32-bit executables should simply run if you have all the required libraries. For development, install [`gcc-multilib`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcc-multilib) [image: Install gcc-multilib], and again possibly other packages that depend on it such as `g++-multilib`. You may find [`binutils-multiarch`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/binutils-multiarch) [image: Install binutils-multiarch] useful as well, and [`ia32-libs-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/ia32-libs-dev) on Debian. Pass the `-m32` option to gcc to compile for ix86.

Note that `uname -m` will still show `x64_64` if you're running a 64-bit kernel, regardless of what 32-bit user mode components you have installed. Schroot described below takes care of this.

### Schroot

This section is a guide to installing a Debian-like distribution “inside” another Linux distribution. It is worded in terms of installing a 32-bit Ubuntu inside a 64-bit Ubuntu, but should apply with minor modifications to other situations, such as installing Debian unstable inside Debian stable or vice versa.

#### Introduction

The idea is to install an alternate distribution in a subtree and run from that. You can install a 32-bit system on a 64-bit system that way, or a different release of your distribution, or a testing environment with different sets of packages installed.

The [`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) command and system call starts a process with a view of the filesystem that's restricted to a subtree of the directory tree. Debian and Ubuntu ship [schroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566), a utility that wraps around this feature to create a more usable sub-environment.

Install the [`schroot` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/schroot) [image: Install schroot] ([Debian](http://packages.debian.org/schroot)) and the [`debootstrap` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/debootstrap) [image: Install debootstrap] ([Debian](http://packages.debian.org/debootstrap)). Debootstrap is only needed for the installation of the alternate distribution and can be removed afterwards.

#### Set up schroot

This example describes how to set up a 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04LTS (lucid lynx) alternate environment. A similar setup should work with other releases of Debian and Ubuntu. Create a file `/etc/schroot/chroot.d/lucid32` with the following contents:

```
[lucid32]
description=Ubuntu 10.04LTS 32-bit
directory=/32
type=directory
personality=linux32
users=yourusername
groups=users,admin
```

The line `directory=/32` tells schroot where we'll put the files of the 32-bit installation. The line  `username=yourusername` says the user `yourusername` will be allowed to use the schroot. The line `groups=users,admin` says that users in either group will be allowed to use the schroot; you can also put a `users=…` directive.

#### Install the new distribution

Create the directory and start populating it with debootstrap. Debootstrap downloads and installs a core set of packages for the specified distribution and architecture.

```
mkdir /32
debootstrap --arch i386 lucid /32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

You almost have a working system already; what follows is minor enhancements. Schroot automatically overwrites several files in `/32/etc` when you run it, in particular the DNS configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf` and the user database in `/etc/passwd` and other files (this can be overridden, see the documentation). There are a few more files you may want to copy manually once and for all:

```
cp -p /etc/apt/apt.conf /32/etc/apt/      # for proxy settings
cp -p /etc/apt/sources.list /32/etc/apt/  # for universe, security, etc
cp -p /etc/environment /32/etc/           # for proxy and locale settings
cp -p /etc/sudoers /32/etc/               # for custom sudo settings
```

There won't be a file `/etc/mtab` or `/etc/fstab` in the chroot. I don't recommend using the `mount` command manually in the chroot, do it from outside. But do create a good-enough `/etc/mtab` to make commands such as `df` work reasonably.

```
ln -s /proc/mounts /32/etc/mtab
```

With the `directory` type, schroot will perform [bind mounts](http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts) of a number of directories, i.e. those directories will be shared with the parent installation: `/proc`, `/dev`, `/home`, `/tmp`.

#### Services in the chroot

As described here, a schroot is not suitable for running daemons. Programs in the schroot will be killed when you exit the schroot. Use a “plain” schroot instead of a “directory” schroot if you want it to be more permanent, and set up permanent bind mounts in `/etc/fstab` on the parent installation.

On Debian and Ubuntu, services start automatically on installation. To avoid this (which could disrupt the services running outside the chroot, in particular because network ports are shared), establish a [policy](http://people.debian.org/%7Ehmh/invokerc.d-policyrc.d-specification.txt) of not running services in the chroot. Put the following script as [`/32/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/runit-policy-rc.d.8.html) and make it executable (`chmod a+rx /32/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`).

```
#!/bin/sh
## Don't start any service if running in a chroot.
## See /usr/share/doc/sysv-rc/README.policy-rc.d.gz
if [ "$(stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/.)" ]; then
  exit 101
fi
```

#### Populate the new system

Now we can start using the chroot. You'll want to install a few more packages at this point.

```
schroot -c lucid32
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install lsb-core nano
...
```

You may need to generate a few locales, e.g.

```
locale-gen en_US en_US.utf8
```

If the schroot is for an older release of Ubuntu such as 8.04 (hardy), note that the package ubuntu-standard pulls in an MTA. Select `nullmailer` instead of the default `postfix` (you may want your chroot to send mail but you definitely don't want it to receive any).

#### Going further

For more information, see the [`schroot` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/schroot.1.html), the [schroot FAQ](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man7/schroot-faq.7.html) and the
[`schroot.conf` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/schroot.conf.5.html). Schroot is part of the [Debian autobuilder (buildd) project](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/buildd-tools). There may be additional useful tips on the [Ubuntu community page about debootstrap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot).

### Virtual machine

If you need complete isolation of the alternate environment, use a virtual machine such as [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) ([qemu-kvm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/qemu-kvm) [image: Install qemu-kvm]) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: @Gilles Can you add an explanation of what the `[ "$(stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/.)" ]` condition does?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It [tests whether the script is running in a chroot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot). It's there to support booting the chroot installation as a standalone system.

Comment: I suggest adding a line like `users=faheem` to your example. By default, for me at least, I'm not a member of the users group. I would have expected to be, however.

Answer (score 31):

Since [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) 11.04 (natty) and [Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/MultiArch) 7.0 (wheezy) introduced [multiarch](http://lwn.net/Articles/482952/) support, 32-bit and 64-bit libraries can coexist on one system. To install a 32-bit library libXX, first add the necessary 32bit architecture to your system:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the 32bit library:

```
sudo apt-get install libXX:i386
```

The ia32-libs package. As of Ubuntu 12.04 precise, it no longer contains any libraries, it only pulls in `libXX:i386` packages as dependencies.

The compile part is rather easy for C and C++ programs, add `-m32` to `CFLAG` or `CXXFLAG`, which will make generated program 32bit, e.g

```
export CFLAGS="-m32"
gcc main.c -o main
```

This works for makefile-based projects as well.

Comment: `apt-get install ia32-libs` worked for me (13.04)!

Comment: for ubuntu 14.04, it's "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386"

Comment: For example, on Debian Jessie:   dpkg --add-architecture i386; apt-get update;  apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libpam0g:i386

Answer (score 5):

If you just have a 32-bit binary you'd like to run on a modern 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu system, do the following:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt install libc6-i386
```

This has been tested on Debian 9.

Comment: I also needed `sudo apt-get install lib32z1` for my particular 32-bit executable, if that helps.  The error was: `sqlite3: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.  Yes, it's 2019 and I can't find a precompiled 64-bit sqlite3 client supported by the sqlite project :(  I'm rather limited in what I am permitted to install on this shared resource so I have to pull down precompiled sqlite packages.  Thankfully I can install `lib32z1`.