# How do I tell I'm running in a chroot?

Tags: chroot

I have a unix installation that's supposed to be usable both as a chroot and as a standalone system. If it's running as a chroot, I don't want to run any service (cron, inetd, and so on), because they would conflict with the host system or be redundant.

How do I write a shell script that behaves differently depending on whether it's running in a chroot? My immediate need is a modern Linux system, with `/proc` mounted in the chroot, and the script is running as root, but more portable answers are welcome as well. (See [How do I tell I'm running in a chroot if /proc is not mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330257/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot-if-proc-is-not-mounted) for the case of Linux without `/proc`.)

More generally, suggestions that work for other containment methods would be interesting. The practical question is, is this system supposed to be running any services? (The answer being no in a chroot, and yes in a full-fledged virtual machines; I don't know about intermediate cases such as jails or containers.)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What I've done here is to test whether the root of the `init` process (PID 1) is the same as the root of the current process. Although `/proc/1/root` is always a link to `/` (unless `init` itself is chrooted, but that's not a case I care about), following it leads to the “master” root directory. This technique is used in a few maintenance scripts in Debian, for example to skip starting udev after installation in a chroot.

```sh
if [ "$(stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/.)" ]; then
  echo "We are chrooted!"
else
  echo "Business as usual"
fi
```

(By the way, this is yet another example of why `chroot` is useless for security if the chrooted process has root access. Non-root processes can't read `/proc/1/root`, but they can follow `/proc/1234/root` if there is a running process with PID 1234 running as the same user.)

If you do not have root permissions, you can look at `/proc/1/mountinfo` and `/proc/$$/mountinfo` (briefly documented in [`filesystems/proc.txt` in the Linux kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)). This file is world-readable and contains a lot of information about each mount point in the process's view of the filesystem. The paths in that file are restricted by the chroot affecting the reader process, if any. If the process reading `/proc/1/mountinfo` is chrooted into a filesystem that's different from the global root (assuming pid 1's root is the global root), then no entry for `/` appears in `/proc/1/mountinfo`. If the process reading `/proc/1/mountinfo` is chrooted to a directory on the global root filesystem, then an entry for `/` appears in `/proc/1/mountinfo`, but with a different mount id. Incidentally, the root field (`$4`) indicates where the chroot is in its master filesystem.

```sh
[ "$(awk '$5=="/" {print $1}' </proc/1/mountinfo)" != "$(awk '$5=="/" {print $1}' </proc/$$/mountinfo)" ]
```

This is a pure Linux solution. It may be generalizable to other Unix variants with a sufficiently similar `/proc` (Solaris has a similar `/proc/1/root`, I think, but not `mountinfo`).

Comment: This won't work in OpenBSD because it has [random PIDs](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix99/full_papers/deraadt/deraadt_html/node18.html); the root process is basically never PID 1.  Now you know why!

Comment: @AdamKatz "... with a couple of obvious exceptions, e.g., init(8)." So which is it?

Comment: @muru: aw, shucks.  You've shot me down.  I'm not sure why `init(8)` would absolutely need to have the #1 slot unless there's some kind of hard-coded nature that requires it (in which I'd still be unsure as to *why*).  Of course, the BSDs have much more advanced jails than just chroot, so I'm not even sure how problematic this is.

Comment: @AdamKatz It's the opposite: pid 1 has a special role (it must reap zombies, and it is immune to SIGKILL). The init program is an implementation of that role. The reason my answer doesn't work in OpenBSD has nothing to do with this: it's because OpenBSD doesn't have anything like Solaris/Linux's `/proc`. My answer wasn't meant to address anything but Linux anyway.

Comment: @Gilles I figured OpenBSD would have this defeated in some manner or other.  Still, I'm surprised that all of those special role items aren't capable of being applied to an arbitrary PID (without consequences), which is what I meant in my italicized "why" earlier.

Comment: Well done, I had to add `sudo` for perm on my system, here is your idea in an alias: `alias ischroot='[ "$(sudo stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(sudo stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/)" ] && echo "Yes, we are chrooted!" || echo "No chroot detected."'`

Comment: @Gilles There is mount_procfs, you can then use `ps` and `grep` to find the init pid.

Comment: You mention checking `mountinfo` for both PID `##` and `1`. Why?

Comment: @sbhatla To compare them. The information a single `mountinfo` file isn't a good test for the process being chrooted. But if the information differs for process 1 and for the running process, that shows that the running process is running in a different root from process 1.

Comment: Having /proc mounted is clearly a security flow, as you can access the real root throw "ls -l /proc/1/root/."

Comment: @Vouze No, having `/proc` mounted is not a security flaw, because chroot alone is not a security mechanism. You can get security from chroot only if the processes running in the chroot run with separate user IDs from processes running outside the chroot. Otherwise chroot does not protect you, for example, from a process that kills or ptraces another process that's running outside the chroot. In that case `/proc/$pid/root` does not permit bypassing the chroot.

Comment: Nice answer; I managed to avoid the subshell substitutions and `[`/`test` with a simple `awk` command: `if stat -c %d:%i / /proc/1/root/. | awk -v RS= '{ exit $1 != $2; }'; then` (setting record separator to empty string automatically makes newline a field separator).  Even easier if your `test` has the `-ef` (same file) comparison!

Answer (score 30):

As mentioned in [Portable way to find inode number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24192/portable-way-to-find-inode-number) and [Detecting a chroot jail from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182/detecting-a-chroot-jail-from-within), you can check whether the inode number of `/` is `2`:

```
$ ls -di /
2 /
```

An inode number that's different from 2 indicates that the apparent root is not the actual root of a filesystem. This will not detect chroots that happen to be rooted on a mount point, or on [operating systems with random root inode numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot/24248?noredirect=1#comment298391_14346).

Comment: On what filesystems does this heuristic work?

Comment: Tested on ext3 and hfs.

Comment: So I was fooling around, and I think I've found a more reliable method that doesn't require root permissions (Linux only). I'm still open to counter-examples or more portable methods.

Comment: This is true for ext[234], but not of all filesystems.  It also only tests that your root is the root of the filesystem, which may not be mounted as the real root.  In other words, if you mount another partition in /jail and `chroot /jail`, then it will look like the real root to this test.

Comment: @Gilles I just wanted to bring your attention to psusi's point (since you were not notified) - the inode number of each separate, "real" filesystem will be `2`. (Exceptions include, for instance, `tmpfs`. I haven't investigated much further.)

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Thanks. I had psusi's concern too: the use case that led me to ask this question was a Linux installation that is designed to work both standalone and as a chroot, so it's on its own partition. The inode heuristic wouldn't work there, but it's a useful one in some controlled environements.

Comment: I noted that OpenBSD has random PIDs in a comment to Gilles's answer.  Similarly, OpenBSD has [random inode numbers](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix99/full_papers/deraadt/deraadt_html/node18.html) (same link), which defeats this technique.  The more I learn about OpenBSD, the more I like it...

Comment: This works well for me, detects perfectly for Crouton running Ubuntu over Chromeos without any need for superuser privileges. `alias ischroot='(($(ls -di / | cut -d" " -f1)==2)) && echo "No chroot detected." || echo "Yes, we are chrooted!"'`

Comment: @AdamKatz Apparently not. Tested in openbsd 6.0-stable, the inode number is still 2 for the actual root path while it's a random number for the chroot.

Answer (score 13):

While clearly not as portable as many other options listed here, if you're on a Debian-based system, try `ischroot`.

See: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/debianutils/ischroot.1.en.html

To get the status in the console directly, using ischroot:

`ischroot;echo $?`

Exit codes:

```
0 if currently running in a chroot
1 if currently not running in a chroot
2 if the detection is not possible (On GNU/Linux this happens if the script is not run as root).
```

Comment: Since `ischroot` is OSS (under GPL2), you can download the source from the official (currently [here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/debianutils)) and `./configure && make ischroot` to compile it. Tested under Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`systemd-detect-virt -r`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html#-r). (must be root)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an accidental observation. But if you have access to anything using FUSE, then you can mount something and then use `mount` to show the mount path, which will be shown with the chroot path prefixed.

E.g., on the Github Actions Mac runner you can do something like:

```bsh
pip install --user ratarmount
folder=$(mktemp -d)
mountedFolder=$(mktemp -d)
# simple bind mount a folder
ratarmount "$folder" "$mountedFolder"
```

Now `mount` will print something like:

```
TarMount on /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/tmp.P5g4TomF (macfuse, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by runner)
```

even though the full path in the `mountedFolder` variable is: `/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/tmp.P5g4TomF`. Therefore it seems we are chrooted into `/private`.

Because of this the hacky `mountpoint` command [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22193352/2191065) using `mount` and `grep` did not work for me.