# Portable way to find inode number

Tags: shell, inode

At first I used `stat -c %i file` (to help [detect the presence of a jail](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/932ba3fbe4dec85f84aea45427f98281ab1a063c/.bashrc#L71)), which seemed to work on any Linux distribution under the sun. On OS X' I had to use `ls -i file | cut -d ' ' -f 1`.

Is there some way to find the inode number of a file in a shell script which is portable across *nix platforms and does not depend on the notoriously capricious `ls`?

Comment: You may be interested in, or have better answers for, [How do I tell I'm running in a chroot?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14345).

Comment: Can you elaborate about the "notoriously capricious ls" ?

Comment: @jlliagre: Others have [done it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) better already.

Comment: Okay, for such files, see my reply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible solution: The [POSIX spec for `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ls.html) specifies `-i`, so maybe it's portable. Does anyone know of a popular implementation of `ls` which does *not* support this, or prints it in a different way from the following example:

```
$ ls -di /
2 /
```

Comment: @greenmang0 He mentioned in the question that it didn't work on OSX

Comment: `ls -di` should just work on OSX just like it should (and likely does) on every Unix/Unix like OS.

Comment: @jlliagre: Please read before posting. The `stat` command didn't work on OS X, `ls -di` worked on both.

Comment: Even Busybox `ls` has `-d` and `-i` as mandatory features (though `ls` itself is optional, like everything else).

Comment: @l0b0: I don't get your reply. I was commenting on Michael Mrozek own comment which states `ls -di` didn't work unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: @jlliagre: Michael said that l0b0's question said that `ls -di` didn't work, but that was a misunderstanding on Michael's part.  In fact, the original question merely says that `stat -c %i file` doesn't work on OSX; `ls -di` should work anywhere.

Comment: Michael misunderstanding was precisely what I was commenting. It doesn't worth a quite rude and undeserved "read before posting" comment.

Comment: There _are_ exceptions to this: `ls` with `-i` front-pads with spaces on at least Solaris 10 (possibly Solaris 11, I haven't checked). It looks like this was the traditional behavior going back to Unix version 7, so I suspect a lot of the corporate *nix flavors kept this behavior (I only have Solaris 10 on-hand though). So near as I can tell, if you use something that properly delineates fields in arbitrary whitespace (so, not `cut`, but for instance `awk` or just the shell's own field-splitting), it's portable to expect the _first_ non-whitespace string to be the inode number.

Comment: @mtraceur Interesting. Shows you just how impossible it is to write truly portable shell code.

Comment: @l0b0 Yeah. It requires masochistic dedication: a bunch of study/testing and memorization for constantly diminishing returns. It's possible, at least for some definition of "portable", but it's not a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 2):

This should be portable and work with file names containing spaces, newlines or other odd characters leading to the *notoriously capricious* ls behavior.

```
filename="whatever file name"
find . -name "$filename" -exec sh -c 'ls -di "$0" | head -1' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

To increase portability you may also implement a platform-specific wrapper function (here called `statinode()`) around the `stat` command that can be based on the output of `uname -s` (see [uname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)).

`ls` would be needed as a fallback option only.

```
(
shopt -s nocasematch nullglob    # using Bash
case "$(uname -s)" in
   # nocasematch alternative
   #[Ll][Ii][Ni][Uu][Xx]   )  statinode() { stat -c '%i' "$@"; return 0; };;
   "Linux"   )      statinode() { stat -c '%i' "$@"; return 0; };;
   "Darwin"  )      statinode() { stat -f '%i' "$@"; return 0; };;
   "FreeBSD" )      statinode() { stat -f '%i' "$@"; return 0; };;
           * )      statinode() { ls -id "$@" | cut -d ' ' -f 1; return 0; };;
esac
#export -f statinode
statinode / / / /
shopt -u nocasematch nullglob
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`stat` is part of the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) package.  OSX uses a different `stat` implementation (presumably a BSD-based one) which doesn't take the same command-line arguments.

You could always install GNU Coreutils on OSX.  Of course that doesn't help if you need a solution that works on OSX systems that don't have GNU Coreutils.

Or, if I'm reading the [OSX stat(1) man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) correctly, `stat -f %i file` on OSX behaves like `stat -c %i file` using the Coreutils version.  (Determining which version of `stat` you have is another matter; you could try `stat --version >/dev/null`; if it succeeds, you have the GNU Coreutils version.)

The `ls -di` solution is more portable and less trouble, but this is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if scalar @ARGV != 1;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my @stat = stat $file;
die "$file: $!\n" if not @stat;
print "$stat[1]\n";
```

You can probably safely assume that Perl is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to jeff's approach, `stat` could be tested directly as well.

```
(
if (stat -c '%i' / 1>/dev/null 2>&1; exit $?); then
   statinode() { stat -c '%i' "$@"; return 0; }
elif (stat -f '%i' / 1>/dev/null 2>&1; exit $?); then
   statinode() { stat -f '%i' "$@"; return 0; }
elif test -n "$(exec 2>/dev/null; ls -id / | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"; then
   statinode() { ls -id "$@" | cut -d ' ' -f 1; return 0; }
else
   echo 'Could not create statinode(). Exiting ...' && exit 1
fi
# export -f statinode
statinode / / / /
declare -f statinode
)
```