# How to find current chroot jail path on Linux <2.6.26

Tags: linux, process, chroot

While running [kernel 2.6.26 or newer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) it's possible to [get the path of the current `chroot` jail](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/f2e452fc2204390e4302fba418292c7669e605f5/.bashrc#L94-97) by comparing the `mountinfo` of the current process and the `init` process. Is there a way to get the same information with kernel <2.6.26?

Comment: Is it ok to require root permissions? (Not that [this related thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot) turned up anything that would help you.)

Comment: @Gilles: Sure, it might still be usable.