# cd to a directory and execute many commands

Tags: bash

I have following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/gentoo
set +e
cd /mnt/gentoo && mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc \
 && mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev \
 && mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys \
 && chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash \
 && source /etc/profile  \
 && export PS1="(chroot)$PS1"
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to change to a directory `/mnt/gentoo` and execute few commands. This works ok first time when none of the path were mounted. But if I run it after mounting has been successfully performed on some paths, it does not continue and stops on first failure. I want all commands to be executed even if mount is failing due to 'already mounted' error. How can I do this?

Also is there a better way than combining all these commands together in one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the `&&` operator between commands, each command runs in sequence, and if any command fails (i.e. returns a nonzero status), the subsequent commands are not executed.

If you want to keep going no matter what, use `;` (or a newline, which is equivalent) instead of `&&`. Here, you need to execute one command, and if it succeeds, execute some more commands whether they succeed or not. One way to achieve this is to put these commands inside a brace group (just `cd … && mount1; mount2` won't work because this executes `mount2` whether or not `cd` succeeds due to precedence).

```
cd /mnt/gentoo && {
  mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc
  mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
  mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
  …
}
```

Alternatively, exit the script or return from the function if `cd` fails.

```
cd /mnt/gentoo || exit $?
mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc
…
```

Alternatively, run under `set -e`, and put `|| true` (“or keep going anyway”) after commands that may fail.

```
set -e
cd /mnt/gentoo
mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc || true
…
```

Alternatively, write a command that must succeed: test if `/proc` and so on are mounted already.

```
mount_if_needed () {
  eval "mount_point=${\$#}"
  awk -v target="$mount_point" '$2 == target {exit(0)} END {exit(1)}' </proc/mounts ||
  mount "$@"
}
set -e
cd /mnt/gentoo
mount_if_needed -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc
```

---

You have another problem where you call `chroot`. You've written: “run bash in the chroot. When bash exits, run `source` and `export`.” That is probably not what you meant. Reading `/etc/profile` can be done by making bash a login shell. A possible way to set `PS1` may be to set it before running bash, but that won't work if `/etc/profile` overrides it, which is common. A better way is to set `PS1` in `~/.bashrc` [if running inside a chroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot) ([`.bashrc`, not `.profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)).

```
chroot . bash --login
```

Debian uses the following code to set `PS1` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` based on the content of `/etc/debian_chroot`:

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Alternatively, for the prompt, use an environment variable instead: run

```
CHROOT_LOCATION=$PWD chroot bash --login
```

and put this in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$CHROOT_LOCATION" ]; then PS1="($CHROOT_LOCATION)$PS1"; fi
```

Answer (score 6):

The `&&` separator in this case is saying 'only continue if the last command was successful'.  If you use `;` instead, the commands will execute in sequence irrespective of results.

Note that if this is a cron job or something else sensitive to stuff being written to stderr, you'll need to redirect the errors to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You don't even need to use `;`. Just put each command on its own line, but you also have to get rid of the `set -e`. If you do not care about command failure, why even use `set -e`? (I know the question asked for one line, but that makes no sense within a script).

Comment: Presumably, it's not a script and is meant to be sourced (though having a she-bang line doesn't make sense then) since it's settings PS1.

Answer (score 0):

Put the command in brackets -  (), so that you return to the current directory, or cd - at the end. If you put this in a file and run it: sh ./my_script.sh it will run the commands in the changed to directory.

```
cd  /mnt/gentoo
mount -t proc none /mnt/gentoo/proc
...
cd -
```

In bash

```
set -e
```

will cause the script to stop running on the first failure. Because you have set +e I would assume you wanted the script to keep running if a command fails.