# Deterministic method to find out whether some other process is in a chroot jail and where?

Tags: linux, process, chroot

**NOTE:** I'm familiar with this U&L Q&A titled: [How do I tell I'm running in a chroot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot) that sounds similar to what I'm asking, but there's a subtle difference to what I'm looking for. That one focuses on the process itself detecting that it's in a chrooted environment, I'm asking how one process to find out that another is chrooted.

---

Was looking into an apache issue in a unfamiliar server. The output of `ps -ef` looked like this:

```
[belmin@server131 ~]$ sudo ps -ef | grep httpd
apache   14363 4082  0 14:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache   14365 4082  0 14:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

I looked in `/usr/local/apache2/conf` for the configuration and it was not what I expected given the symptoms we were seeing. Decided to double check the `init` script and noticed the actual process was in a chroot jail.

For future reference, is there a way of figuring out if a process is in a `chroot` jail with just the `PID`? And how would I find out the path of the `chroot` jail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `/proc/<pid>/root`. This is a symbolic link to the process's root directory. If it doesn't link to `/`, the process is in a chroot jail.