# How do I tell I'm running in a chroot if /proc is not mounted?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I wanted to find whether I am inside a `chroot` as part of a script where I'm not allowed to mount `/proc` if it is not (unlike the case in [How do I tell I'm running in a chroot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot)). How to find whether I'm in a `chroot` even if `/proc` is not mounted?

I do have root access. This is on Fedora. The solution should not depend on the filesystems used.

Answer (score 0):

Debian chroot put a specific file to `/etc`, but this need cooperation.

But if it is like normal root, it is like normal root. So if you don't find differences, assume that you are not in chroot (in any case it is equivalent).

The hard way is to check if `/` is the same as what you will get mounting the root device, but this requires you to be root. Other methods requires `/proc` (or root).

Comment: Is there anything like /etc check available for Fedora? I can't get things mounted on `/`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`systemd-detect-virt -r`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html#-r). (must be root)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other answers, this one doesn't need you to be root. Run `unshare -U true`. If it succeeds, then you're not in a chroot. If it fails with `unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted`, then you are. This works because of [commit `3151527ee007b73a0ebd296010f1c0454a919c7d`: userns: Don't allow creation if the user is chrooted](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3151527ee007b73a0ebd296010f1c0454a919c7d).

Caveat: `unshare` can fail for a few other reasons too. If it succeeds, then you're definitely not in a chroot, but if it fails, then you only probably are.