# What can cause different processes to see different mount points?

Tags: ssh, kernel, mount, cron

I am really struggling to get to the bottom of [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79097/cron-and-atd-jobs-cant-see-manually-mounted-file-systems).

For some reason cron cannot see a file system I mounted manually.  This is a USB drive formatted to ext4 mounted to `/backup`.  For completeness I mounted it while logged into SSH, not directly at a terminal.

If I compare typing `mount | sort` at the commandline (over ssh) with the same command over `cron` or `atd` the cron version will miss the lines:

```
tmpfs on /run/sshd type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /backup type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

I've confirmed that neither cron nor sshd are `chroot`ed using [the accepted answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot).

**If neither are chrooted, then what else can cause two different processes to see different mounts?**

This is really causing a problem because my backups keep writing to the 30GB SD card in my r-pi instead of the 2TB USB hard drive.

---

**Edit** for future reference. This bug in Systemd v236 looks like the cause.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7761

---

If I type

```
mount | sort
```

I get

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/mercury_data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /root type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /backup type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=470180k,nr_inodes=117545,mode=755)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/sshd type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
```

But when I run this through `cron` or `atd` I get:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/mercury_data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /root type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=470180k,nr_inodes=117545,mode=755)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
```

Comment: I think this is only due to environnement (not similar in shell & crontab or at )

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I don't believe it's specific to those daemons, but I mention it in case there is a new trend to isolate them in some way I'm not aware of.

Comment: Have you discounted any restrictions regarding SELinux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the daemons are running in different mount namespaces, so changes you make in your SSH session aren’t visible in `cron` or `at` jobs. Look at `mountinfo` and `ns/mnt` inside the various deamons’ `/proc/${pid}` directories to check which namespaces they’re using and what they can inherit.

Comment: yes, on the ssh command line `ls -lh /proc/1/ns/mnt /proc/self/ns/mnt` shows different numbers.  This shows my SSH session is in a different namespace to the main system.  Further digging, my cron daemon is in the main (same as `init`) namespace so the problem is the way sshd is being loaded.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay.  Lots more digging. Looks like a known bug in systemd for this version.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7761

Comment: Nice digging! It does look like that’s the issue...