# Automatically execute `nix-user-chroot` when I start a terminal session (Steam Deck)

Tags: bash, arch-linux, chroot, nix

I am running Arch Linux on the Steam Deck. Steam Deck has a read only root file system which forces you to use Flatpak, or else to make the file system writable at the expense of wiping out, say, pacman-based installations [every time they update the Deck's software](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/671A-4453-E8D2-323C).

I'm not a fan of Flatpak, I prefer Nix not least because it has packages that I need that are not available with Flatpak.

Nix allows you to run the entire package manager without root access from a chroot jail using [nix-user-chroot](https://github.com/nix-community/nix-user-chroot) utility.

Once installed, the command for getting into the chrooted nix environment is `nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l` which works fine in a new shell:

[image]

However if I stick that exact same line at the end of my `.bashrc` I get a panic:

[image]

This appears to be exactly the same error that occurs if I run the command twice:

[image]

Keep in mind that the Steam Deck's shell already appears to be running in a chroot jail, as per [this technique](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24248/46385) for finding out if I'm already chrooted (run without the `nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l` in my bashrc):

[image]

So my question is, how do I automatically run `nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l` so that it is invoked for every terminal?

Comment: @moderators you might want to create a new 'steam-deck' tab because I anticipate this brilliant little machine's funky Arch installation will get quite a few questions on your forum. I cannot as don't have 300 yet.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000) Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Also, if you do `SOME_FLAG_VARIABLE=1  nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l`, is the `SOME_FLAG_VARIABLE` environment variable available in the chroot shell? (It should be, but this `nix-user-chroot` command might clean the environment.) If it is, you can just check for that variable before executing the command in your bashrc: `if [[ -z SOME_FLAG_VARIABLE ]]; then exec SOME_FLAG_VARIABLE=1 nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As muru mentioned in the comment, the problem is that the first execution of `nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l` works fine, but spawns a new shell which again tries to execute `nix-user-chroot` etc. The solution is to put the `nix-user-chroot` inside an if-clause, checking if the nix environment is already loaded, e.g. running

```bash
if [ -z "${NIX_PROFILES}" ]; then
    ./nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash -l
fi
```

*after* loading your nix profile (there's a line added by the installer either in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` file).

Answer (score 1):

I do something a bit different and change Konsole's command in `Settings`->`Edit Current Profile...` to:

```
/bin/bash -c "~/.local/bin/nix-user-chroot ~/.nix bash"
```

<sub>I have to create a new profile as the `Vapor` one is read only.</sub>

It does almost the same thing. It's only in Konsole so if I do ++ my bash still works in case I need to fix something :)

Then for apps I create an executable bash script in `~/.local/bin/<YOURAPPNAME>` and make it executable `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/<YOURAPPNAME>` with this content:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

~/.local/bin/nix-user-chroot ~/.nix ~/.nix-profile/bin/<YOURAPPNAME>
```

And for desktop use I create `~/.local/share/applications/<YOURAPPNAME>.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=<YOURAPPNAME>
Comment=<YOURAPPDESCRIPTION>
Exec=~/.local/bin/<YOURAPPNAME>
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=meld
Categories=GNOME;Development;
StartupNotify=false
NoDisplay=false
```