# qemu no boot device found!

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I am trying to set up a Linux x86_64 virtual machine on a 32bit Linux computer and I've been told aqemu's Wizard is a good option. I can follow the wizard steps, but when I try to start the virtual machine, I receive a "No boot devices found!" error. Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That usually indicates that you don't have a bootable hard disk or CD/DVD image attached.  Check your virtual machine's configuration and make sure you have a bootable ISO for a LiveCD or installer mounted.

That message could also indicate that you're attempting to boot a 64-bit operating system in a 32-bit virtualized environment.  Make sure your VM is configured to be 64-bit, as in this example:

[image: 64-bit aqemu example]

Comment: thx, but this didnt work for me ...