# How to determine bitness of hardware and OS?

Tags: linux, hardware, 64bit, architecture

Output of `uname` -a on my RHEL 5.4 machine is:

```
Linux <machine name> 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does it mean that hardware is 64 bit (going by perhaps first x86_64) and OS is also 64-bit going by last x86_64?

Also, what are these so many instances of x86_64?
Can I install 64-bit vm over 32-bit OS and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hardware, the kernel and the user space programs may have different word sizes¹.

- You can see whether the **CPU** is 64-bit, 32-bit, or capable of both by checking the `flags` line in `/proc/cpuinfo`. You have to know the possible flags on your architecture family. For example, on i386/amd64 platforms, the `lm` flag identifies amd64-capable CPUs (CPUs that don't have that flag are i386-only).

  ```
    grep -q '^flags *:.*\blm\b' /proc/cpuinfo    # Assuming a PC
  ```
- You can see whether the kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit by querying the architecture with `uname -m`. For example, `i[3456]86` are 32-bit while `x86_64` is 64-bit. Note that on several architectures, a 64-bit kernel can run 32-bit userland programs, so even if the `uname -m` shows a 64-bit kernel, there is no guarantee that 64-bit libraries will be available.

  ```
    [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]    # Assuming a PC
  ```
- You can see what is available in userland by querying the [LSB](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/lsb.shtml) support with the [`lsb_release`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) command. More precisely, `lsb_release -s` prints a `:`-separated list of supported LSB features. Each feature has the form `module-version-architecture`. For example, availability of an ix86 C library is indicated by `core-2.0-ia32`, while `core-2.0-amd64` is the analog for amd64. Not every distribution declares all the available LSB modules though, so more may be available than is detectable in this way.
- You can see what architecture programs on the system are built for with a command like `file /bin/ls`. Note that it's possible to have a mixed system; even if `ls` is a 64-bit program, your system may have libraries installed to run 32-bit programs, and (less commonly) vice versa.
- You can find out the preferred word size for development (assuming a C compiler is available) by compiling a 5-line C program that prints `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(size_t)`. You can obtain the same information in a slightly less reliable way² by running the command `getconf LONG_BIT`.

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(void*));
        return 0;
    }
  ```

As for virtual machines, whether you can run a 64-bit VM on a 32-bit system or vice versa depends on your virtual machine technology. See in particular
[How can I install a 64bit Linux virtual machine on a 32bit Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15786/how-can-i-install-a-64bit-linux-virtual-machine-on-a-32bit-linux)

¹  <sub>“Word size” is the usual name for what you call bitness.</sub> 
²  <sub>It can be unreliable if someone installed an alternate C compiler with a different target architecture but kept the system default `getconf`.</sub>

Comment: Hi Gilles, 

    "file `which init` "

may be a hack worth adding to the list. ( An off-topic: did you ever write any books on Unix ? I'd buy one ) )

Comment: While we are at finding out the real size of an integer type in C: An ages old trick is assigning a constant "1" to a variable, then counting how many times you can left shift it before anything untoward happens.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder of `getconf LONG_BIT`, looks like `inxi` lacks this particular test.

Comment: ` lsb-release -s` didn't work for me, it said: Command 'lsb-release' not found, did you mean: command 'lsb_release' from deb lsb-release. So I guess it should be ` lsb_release -s`

Answer (score 1):

You wondered about `uname`'s multiple x86_64 occurrences:

```
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
```

That's those three values (*"omit -p and -i if unknown"*)

```
    -m, --machine 
          print the machine hardware name
    -p, --processor
          print the processor type or "unknown"
    -i, --hardware-platform
          print the hardware platform or "unknown"
```

Note that `-p` and `-i` are not part of [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html). The values are `unknown` on Debian, so uname would print x86_64 only once.  Red Hat/CentOS defines the value.

Also read: [How does Linux `uname -m` get its information?](https://superuser.com/q/762616) and [Why do uname -p and uname -m and arch output different architectures?](https://superuser.com/q/835514).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **`man uname`**.

You can compile and run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit machine (though this requires a special setup), but can't run 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit system. Same applies to many Virtual Machines, [but not all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines)<sup>*</sup>. So if you have a 64bit kernel, there's no way that your hardware is 32-bit-only.

If you want to test for what bitness a binary program is made, run `file /path/to/the/program`.

<sup>* This depends on the level, on which a given Virtual Machine operates: Those that execute binary code (almost) directly on the host CPU, will not be able to run 64-bit code on a 32-bit host. Those that *emulate* a certain CPU can do it, but they are less efficient because of the emulation level.</sup>

Comment: You can compile 64bit binaries on 32bit systems, just not run them. And 32bit VM could emulate a 64bit CPU.

Comment: Good point about compiling - my bad. The second part depends on the VM software, IIRC.

Comment: Some VM packages can run 64-bit guest OSes (and 64-bit software within them) natively on a 64-bit CPU, even if the host OS is 32-bits.

Comment: @DavidS Good point as well... Still, no way that could be done on a 32-bit CPU.