# How do I identify which Linux distro is running?

Tags: linux, version

We have some new hardware in our office which runs its own customized Linux OS.

How do I go about figuring which distro it's based on?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

A question very close to this one was posted on Unix.Stackexchange [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24717/how-to-determine-bitness-of-hardware-and-os)
`Giles` has a pretty complete | cool answer for the ways he describes.

```
# cat /proc/version

Linux version 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b6.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011
```

```
# uname -a

Linux system1.doofus.local 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# cat /etc/issue

CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

`cat /proc/config.gz` `cat /usr/src/linux/config.gz` `cat /boot/config*`

Though I did some checking and this was not very reliable except on SUSE.

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -i kernel
CONFIG_SUSE_KERNEL=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_DESKTOP is not set
CONFIG_LOCK_KERNEL=y
```

Release Files in `/etc` ([from Unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/27932-how-know-linux-distribution-i-am-using.html))

- Novell SuSE---> /etc/SuSE-release
- Red Hat--->/etc/redhat-release, /etc/redhat_version
- Fedora-->/etc/fedora-release
- Slackware--->/etc/slackware-release, /etc/slackware-version
- Old Debian--->/etc/debian_release, /etc/debian_version
- New Debian--->/etc/os-release
- Mandrake--->/etc/mandrake-release
- Yellow dog-->/etc/yellowdog-release
- Sun JDS--->/etc/sun-release
- Solaris/Sparc--->/etc/release
- Gentoo--->/etc/gentoo-release

There is also a bash script at the Unix.com link someone wrote to automate checking.

Figuring out what package manager you have is a good clue.

`rpm` `yum` `apt-get` `zypper` +many more

Though this is by no means foolproof as the vendor could use anything they want. It really just gives you a place to start.

```
# dmesg | less

Linux version 2.6.32.12-0.7-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP 2010-05-20 11:14:20 +0200
```

pretty much the same information as `cat /proc/version` & `uname`

Comment: If you are in a container, beware cat /proc/version will give the host distro, not the container one.

Comment: Note that this should be `cat /etc/*elease` for centos http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54987/how-to-know-centos-version#comment400919_54988

Comment: @hawkeye I find  ls /etc | grep release  to be more effective, as it also will pick up files named release-XX, for example

Comment: Note that most of these tell you about the KERNEL, not the distribution. As the files indicated above show, cat /etc/*release is probably the most general way of seeing the distribution.

Comment: I have down voted this because `cat /proc/version` gives wrong answer, e.g. CentOS7 will claim it is "Red Hat 4.8.5". Please upvote the correct answer listed further down: `cat /etc/*-release`

Answer (score 52):

You'll want to use:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
```

You'll get a response similar to this:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Note that stuff in "/proc" tells you about the *kernel* (or in this case the distribution that the compiler was built with that built the running kernel), not the *distribution* itself. Since getting this information is in inherently distribution-specific, the /etc/*-release is the most general way.

Comment: The Ubuntu-16.04 on my desktop has an `/etc/os-release` files, whereas the CentOS-7 on our number cruncher has an `/etc/system-release` file. At least they got the `-release` suffix in common.

Answer (score 20):

As a first guess, try `lsb_release -a`. E.g. on an Arch Linux system it gives

> LSB Version:  n/a 
>   Distributor ID: archlinux 
>   Description:    Arch Linux 
>   Release:    rolling 
>   Codename:   n/a

However, this might fail, then you will have to poke around `/etc` (most likely it is inside a file whose name ends with `-release`). Also `cat /etc/issue` might help.

Comment: *lsb_release -a* returns "-bash: lsb_release: command not found" on Raspberry with [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) ([Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) 7.1 derived).

Comment: You'll have to install the `lsb-release` package.