# How to determine CentOS version?

Tags: centos, version

How do I determine the version of a CentOS server without access to any graphical interface? I've tried several commands:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-128.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc1-7.build.redhat.com)
(gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)) …

# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)
```

but which one is correct: 4.1.2-4 from `/proc/version` or 5.3 from `/etc/issue`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As you can see in `/etc/issue`, you're using CentOS 5.3. (It says Red Hat because CentOS is based upon the RH sources, and some software checks `/etc/issue` to identify the distro in use; thus, they'd fail if this was changed to CentOS).

The `4.1.2-4` in `/proc/version` refers to the version of the `gcc` C compiler used to build the kernel.

Comment: I'll just add, what You could use uname -a to detect, if it 32 or 64 bit compatible.

Comment: On CentOS 7, 'cat /etc/issue' yields gobbledygook:

`\S
Kernel \r on an \m`

Comment: Correct answer should be the one by h3rrmiller... `cat /etc/*elease`. `/etc/issue` is often replaced by an organisation's MOTD/disclaimer

Comment: The `/etc/issue` file shows that it is RHEL, not CentOS.

Comment: crappy answer. I dont know why is it accepted

Answer (score 180):

In cases like CentOS the actual version is usually placed in `/etc/*elease`.

```
cat /etc/*elease
```

granted this file usually holds the version of the entire OS minus the kernel (since you can choose which to load).
This file will have the same information as /etc/issue but with CentOS instead of RedHat

Comment: cat /etc/*release will work too, and you are not omitting a letter of what are you looking for ;) because elease is not always easy to guess. `*` can be nothing, all, one or more items at time. Thank you, i always forgot the way to get the release version.

Comment: The reason I leave the "R" off is because in some cases the "R" in "release" is capitalized.

Comment: Just to say, doing `ls /etc/*elease` on my system gives `/etc/centos-release  /etc/redhat-release  /etc/system-release`.  So I'm guessing from all this that the release files tend to be in `/etc/*-release` - but possibly with some capitalisation.

Comment: This is correct. I find at many sites that `/etc/issue` has been overwritten with an MOTD or security disclaimer for use with the `Banner` option in `sshd_config`

Comment: `cat /etc/*os-release` should yield more targetted results for CentOS and still work on Ubuntu and others.

Comment: This.  My boss kept asking me, "what's the file called?" on a Debian system and I could not answer him.  I just kept answering "just cat etsy star lease."  This tends to work on most current/common Linux systems.

Answer (score 20):

The **most reliable way** of finding *MAJOR* version of CentOS (5 or 6 etc) is:

```
# rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' centos-release
6
```

For RHEL do this:

```
# rpm -q --queryformat '%{RELEASE}' redhat-release-server | awk -F. '{print $1}'
7
```

The only portable way of finding out a version **without** lsb_release or other tools is:

```
# grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /etc/redhat-release
6.5
```

Comment: Can be simplified to: `cat /etc/redhat-release | grep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9]'`

Comment: +1 `rpm -q centos-release` is the only way I have yet found to get the minor version on older CentOS5 releases where /etc/redhat-release only contains the major version. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: To get the major version: `cat /etc/redhat-release | grep -oP '(?<= )[0-9]+(?=\.)'`

Comment: Just curious: why "cat file | grep pattern" instead of "grep pattern file"?

Comment: Right, digged that from shell history and was able to correct this. Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

You can determine it by just calling the following command:

```
hostnamectl
```

Which will return as the following:

```
Static hostname: mgbcctli01
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: de14d80a0900427894dbcf6137e058e7
       Boot ID: 6865f9839c064bc9be32281d0f262cc8
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
   CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
        Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

You can also use `rpm` to find details about CentOS version:

```
rpm --query centos-release
```

Which will return in my case:

```
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: `hostnamectl` only returns the  major release number

Comment: That's right, using rpm, you can get a detailed version

Answer (score 6):

Correct way is `lsb_release -d`.

Comment: On CentOS 7: lsb_release: Command not found.

Comment: yum install redhat-lsb-core ...

Comment: Sure, but I meant: I'm not sure is valuable to have to install a new package to get the current version.

Comment: If you want some command which is able to do so across multiple distributions it may still be worth installing.

Answer (score 6):

The most *truly* reliable (and short) way to get MAJOR version of either CentOS or RHEL is:

```
rpm -E %{rhel}
```

Will give you a value of e.g. `6`, `7`, or `8` (now that RHEL 8 is out).

Answer (score 5):

```
# echo "I am running: `cat /etc/redhat-release` (`arch`)"
```

Outputs the following:

```
I am running: CentOS release 6.7 (Final) (x86_64)
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be found at the location `/etc`, inside the file `os-release`. So type in:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Was this backported to CentOS 5 or 6? If not, this is mostly useful going forward....

Comment: CentOS made this available starting with CentOS 7 - I've not seen a backport.

Answer (score 2):

Run `rpm --eval '%{centos_ver}'` to get MAJOR version of centos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some command I collected through google, may help someone:

https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=15878

```
cat /etc/*release*
cat /etc/centos-release
```

http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-check-your-centos-version/

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-centos-version

```
# the later two may need some package to install
rpm --query centos-release
hostnamectl
lsb_release -d
```

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Shellbye/03dc1619cd92db83db865a59317b7a4b) to record this, too.