# Extract creation date and modification time of file in SunOS?

Tags: files, ksh, timestamps

I want to extract creation date of a file and modification time. The format should be (`yyyymmddhh24miss`).

- My unix shell `/usr/bin/ksh`
- The file: `file.txt`
- My system: *SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-23 sun4v sparc sun4v*

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287008/stat-command-not-found

Comment: Similar: [Solaris + display file time stamp \[year\]\[month\]\[day\]](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/57626)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```sh
perl -MPOSIX -l -e \
'print strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime((lstat)[9]) for @ARGV' file.txt
```

Comment: That is not the creation time, it's the time of last modification. Solaris does not, as far as I see, store the time of creation of files.