# Why when I use Arch In a VM In Virtualbox, it loops checking the NAT Adapter?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

For some reason, when I boot Arch on a VM in Virtualbox it boots and then goes into what send like an infinite loop of Last To Clean and all that, and it won't let me use the command line.

This might not be a network issue but it needs to be fixed and I don't know how to do that.
.
Can anyone help?

Comment: If it has the full desktop  environment it isn't net-install. I would try reinstalling maybe try following a guide for Arch installing. If you want to recover the one you are working with you could see if there is some sort of shortcuts. You could also connect a usb dongle and see if connecting that USB device to the VM works for enabling it to connect to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

So you were trying to boot arch linux in a vm with the nat setting on and it got stuck. Did you look here  [Stuck while loading kernel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_troubleshooting#Stuck_while_loading_the_kernel)  ? You if it is really the nat setting causing the problem you could also try to use a wireless dongle and use the USB pass through vm setting and see if it works.

Comment: I Will Try To Install On My PC First Then I Will Try That, Also Do You Mean USB Drive Or USB Internet That You Normally Plug Into The Back Of The Computer Tower

Comment: Install On My PC? I Meant, With The NAT Network On My PC In Virtualbox

Comment: USB wireless adapter.

Comment: Ok So I Have A Dualband Wireless Adapter But, My Sis Lives With Me And She Is Using One Of My PC's And Is Using It

Comment: Also Like You Said That Stuff Looks To Need The Command Line And Again It Wont Let Me Use The Command Line At All

Comment: And The Arch Wiki Probably Doesn't Have A Guide To Setup Issues In Virtualbox

Comment: At The Moment My Computer Has 4 GB RAM But That Is MORE Than Enough To Run Arch Correctly

Comment: That's Weird It Wont Allow Me To Do Arch x64 That Also Concerns Me Because I Downloaded x64 not x32

Comment: It Only Lets Me Do 32 Bit For Every OS

Comment: My Computer Is 32 bit, Now I Have To Reinstall Arch wich took half an hour to download

Comment: Also It Gives Me The Oppurtunity To Setup A VM For Ubuntu Budgie Wich Is Awesome, Apparently I Dont Know How To Type Wich Correctly

Comment: the mystery is solved can't run a 64 bit on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: not necesarilly it doesnt fix the fact that it does the thing with the NAT

Comment: i  was running x64 bit machine with x64 bit arch in virtualbox and i got the loop of the stuff caused by the NAT Network Adapter

Comment: A Little Off Topic But What IS Solaris???

Comment: And You Can Run MAC in Virtualbox wait, isn't that against Apples TOS

Comment: Anyway Be Back In About 3 Hours thats how long arch 32 bit takes to download WOWWWW!!!!!

Comment: You can run 64bit images on a 32bit OS as long as the processor chip can support it. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15813/100397