# virtualenv type tool for apt-get?

Tags: package-management, apt

Is there anyway or any popular tool that can allow me to create an isolated package environment for apt-get similar to what virtualenv does for pip and python packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking after is the combination of [schroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566) and [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). Schroot is a utility that essentially lets you run a Linux distribution inside another. Debootstrap is a utility to install a (Debian-based) distribution inside another. See [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu) (which is easily generalized to running a Debian or Ubuntu-based distribution inside another).

Answer (score 1):

See [pbuilder](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder.html.en) and 
[cowbuilder](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cowbuilder) for example.

See also [Package builders](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/tools.html#tools-builders) and [Isolated build environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_build_toolchain#Isolated_build_environments).

The last link has a succinct overview of pbuilder and sbuild.