# Will my programs installed in Ubuntu be usable by another distro in a dual-boot set-up?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, dual-boot

I am interested in setting up my machine so that I can try different distributions of Linux.  I want to always be running Ubuntu (10.04.3), but would then try other distros in a dual-boot setting.

Since the file hierarchy will be similar, I am wondering if the programs that I install and the settings in Ubuntu will work on the 2nd/test distro side?

If so, does it make sense to mount `/opt`, `/usr` `/etc` `/var` each on a separate partition so that I can then mount the same files in the corresponding folders the 2nd/test distro side?

Is it worth it to try to use these files in both systems simutaneously?  Or is it easier just to change settings and re-download programs in each system?  If yes, why?  If no, why not?

I am speculating that it will depend heavily on the distro, so if that is the case, then answer the question for:

- Linux Mint, and
- all other Debian based distros.

(ie, "would this work for all Debian based systems?" -- I am not looking for an answer for each one.)

---

Update by OP:

1. It was dumb to suggest moving /etc to a separate partition: [According to the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/directory-tree.html), the root partition must always contain /etc or else you can't boot.

Comment: Assuming it worked well: If you replace the 2nd distros programs and settings by Ubuntu's, you won't be running that second distro, you'd be essentially running Ubuntu with that distro's kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run programs from another distribution. However, not all programs will run straight out of the box. A number of programs need files in a specific place or on the search path, that your main distribution might not provide or might provide in a version that isn't suitable. For example, if a program needs a particular library that's only in `/otherdistribution/usr/lib`, it won't find that library unless you tell it where (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/otherdistribution/usr/lib /otherdistribution/usr/bin/someprogram`). Or if a program is looking for its data files in `/usr/share/myprogram`, you need to tell it to look in `/otherdistribution/usr/share/myprogram` somehow.

If you want to run a distribution and occasionally run programs from another distribution (or another version of that same distribution, say Debian stable and Debian testing), the easiest approach is to access other distributions through [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). And the easiest way to do that on Debian-based distributions is through [schroot](http://enricozini.org/2008/tips/joys-of-schroot/) (you may find
[this guide to setting up a schroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu) useful).

Answer (score 3):

For /opt it makes sense, for the other's not. Just compare library versions and your /etc directories' layout.

In fact with /opt I did more or less the same. My /opt directory had withstanded several distro upgrades and changes. Although every now and then you might need to fiddle around.

Comment: This is what I will do.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application, how it was linked (static or dynamic) and whether all relevant files are placed within reach of the application folder.

Use `ldd` on the binaries/libraries of the application to see the dependencies. No dependency should be shown as "missing". If you have a lot of specific dependencies live gets harder.