# application requires 32bit libs be installed on my 64 bit system -- having trouble installing them

Tags: compiling, drivers, video, 64bit, 32bit

I want to install SimpleScreenRecorder (SSR) from git as recommended by the developer. The binary version crashes while the git version fixes my crash problem. Unfortunately, to build the git version I have to resort to a work-around -- and now I've run into side effects from that.

[Main page - SimpleScreenRecorder - Maarten Baert's website](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)

The instructions are found here: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr

The dev says, "I don't know whether this is the right way to do it, but it works for me."

It worked for me too, but it is not nice in situations such as changing video drivers (which I'm doing now).

Therefore, I decided to come ask the experts here for a better solution. I'm hoping someone knows the right way to resolve this.

(BTW, I asked a similar but different question and answered it myself here: https://askubuntu.com/a/347620/36661) I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 with the lts-raring hardware enablement stack.

The problem is that the 64-bit portion of the build works, but the 32-bit portion fails due to some libraries missing. The proposed workaround involves manually creating symlinks to make up for the "missing" libraries. Here are my build/install steps including the workaround symlink creation:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev g++-multilib ia32-libs
cd /workspaces/ (or any path you choose - see note below)
git clone https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr.git (in my case the project path is /workspaces/ssr/)
sudo mkdir /usr/lib32/fglrx/
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1 /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so  # only for proprietary AMD drivers!
# SKIP: sudo ln -s fglrx/libGL.so /usr/lib32/libGL.so    # only for proprietary AMD drivers!
sudo ln -s libGLU.so.1 libGLU.so
sudo ln -s libX11.so.6 libX11.so
sudo ln -s libXext.so.6 libXext.so
sudo ln -s libXfixes.so.3 libXfixes.so
sudo ldconfig
cd /path/to/ssr (will be the ssr directory under `/workspaces/` in my example)
$ ./simple-build-and-install
```

So, what's the right way to solve the problem so that I don't have to create these symlinks and so that the app won't break if I change video drivers?

Is there an IRC channel that is appropriate for this question?

Comment: Why not install the 32-bit versions of the libraries?

Comment: @slm - I was just reading this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47003/15010. Can you tell what which 32-bit packages I need to install based on the symlinks in the workaround?

Comment: I should also mention that I need to use libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring instead of libgl1-mesa-dev.

Comment: So far, no luck... I tried `apt-get install libx11-dev:386` but there is no such package. (It was just a guess on my part anyway.)

Comment: Try :i386 instead.

Comment: @slm - thanks. I misread that. `XXX:i386` works. Any idea which 386 packages I need to install?

Comment: Total guesses but I would search for packages using the .so files you're linking above. `apt-cache search ...`. For example libX11-dev:i386, libglu1-mesa-dev:i386, etc.

Comment: @slm: here are my guesses: libx11-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxfixes-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring:i386 mesa-common-dev-lts-raring:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:i386 libdrm-dev:i386

Comment: @slm - Thanks for your help. I'm going to try building it now.

Comment: @slm: didn't work. The errors are like: `libxext-dev : Conflicts: libxext-dev:i386 but 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1 is to be installed`