# What software allows the change of runtime-environment, while keeping the same kernel running?

Tags: linux, kernel, distributions, virtualization

I know that with a GNU/Linux distribution you can switch between different distributions at runtime when they use the same kernel or the kernel is compatible between 2 or more different distributions; I never used this feature of the Linux-based OSs, but I would like to ask what is the software/s that makes this possible and how to perform this switch at runtime correctly.

It will be nice to also have a list of pros and cons, for example what settings I loose and what I can keep during the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization), which can take many forms. One OS is running on the physical hardware, and the other OSes are running in a more or less virtual environment.

If you want to run very different operating systems (for example Linux and Windows), run one of them in a virtual machine.

At the other extreme, if you want to have access to programs from several distributions (for example a stable distribution and a bleeding edge distribution), all running the same kernel, you can install one of the distributions in a directory subtree and run its programs inside the directory subtree thanks to the [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) command. For an example of how to do this on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, see [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu)

Linux offers more complex features to run multiple Linux systems off the same kernel: [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC), [namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/namespace), …