# Install specific 32 bit package on 64 bit debian squeeze(6.0)

Tags: debian

I have an amd64 installation of Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), where I need to install a 32 bit version of the libpcap0.8.

I have done an `apt-get install ia32-libs` which gets me a 32 bit libc and a few other things, but now I need another specific 32 bit package.

What do I have to do ?

(EDIT: the [suggested duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu) is for Debian 7 and Ubuntu, and does not work on Debian 6)

Comment: You should use the 2nd (not accepted) answer of the duplicate that suggests using multiarch.

Comment: @terdon How so ? That approach does not work on Debian 6.0. (The answer might ofcourse be that it simply can't be done on Squeeze, but I don't know)

Comment: My bad, I missed that you were on squeeze. The first approach (schroot) should work though. If not, [edit] this question and explain that you tried it and it failed, then the Q will be reopened.

Comment: Did you also try the `schroot` approach?

Comment: Nothing in the duplicate works? I think it was intended to be a comprehensive answer for most/all Ubuntu and Debian versions

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Squeeze is pre-multiarch. IMO OP should use stable instead since it will save him several headaches

Comment: You're really better off moving to wheezy. Is there some reason you can't?