# Run 64-bit app on 32-bit Ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64bit, 32bit

All the questions I've seen refer to running a 32-bit app in a 64-bit system.

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 (actually elementary OS Luna, which is based on it) and I'm trying to run a 64-bit app which refuses open. Running:

```
./64bit_app.run
```

(where `64bit_app.run` is the 64-bit app I'm trying to run) results in:

```
bash: ./64bit_app.run: no se puede ejecutar el fichero binario
```

which translates to "*can't execute/run/open binary file*".

Should I be able to run it? Is it possible to run a 64-bit app in a 32-bit system? If so, how?

Comment: I have _not_ tried this but have you attempted the solutions shown [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/22222), esoecially the answer explaining `dpkg --add-architecture`? As far as I know, the same approach should work for 32 on 64 and for 64 on 32. Just change `dpkg --add-architecture i386` to `dpkg --add-architecture amd64`.

Comment: you _do_ have 64-bit hardware, right? (just to make sure)

Comment: "which refuses open"? how exactly?

Comment: @strugee my hardware supports 64 bit (`lscpu` returns `CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit`), but my systems is 32 bit.
@Braiam the error reads: "_can't execute binary file_" (translated from Spanish)

Comment: @terdon tried adding `dpkg --add-architecture amd64` to the `./64bit_app.run` line but it did not work.

Comment: What `./64bit_app` line? Please [edit] your post explaining any steps you've tried.

Comment: @terdon just did.

Comment: Please read the answers to the question I [linked to](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/22222), you need to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64` first. That's a separate command.

Comment: @terdon sorry, I did not understand that. Running that line results in: `dpkg: error: opción --add-architecture desconocida` where `desconocida` translates to `unknown`.

Comment: Gabriel, ah yes, sorry Ubuntu's dpkg does not seem to have that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that directly on Linux on x86_64 with a 32bit kernel. You need a 64bit kernel to be able to run 64bit code. (Note: kernel. You can have 32bit userland running on a 64bit kernel, and install support for 64bit binaries. How easy this is depends on the distribution. Example [here](http://neuro.debian.net/blog/2013/2013-05-31_matlab_64bit_on_32bit.html) for Debian.)

Some virtualization software is able to do that (with restrictions on the type of CPU you're using), and emulators can do that too. But to run it natively you'll need a 64bit kernel.

Since most 64bit distributions out there have 32bit support (either by default or installable), that's what you should be using if you need to run both 64bit and 32bit binaries on the same OS.

Answer (score 8):

Extending @Mat's answer:

Yes, some virtualization software can do it. The main obstacle to handle is that in a 32-bit environment, the 64-bit features of the CPU are not available, and also the features of a 64-bit kernel isn't available. It is even so if your CPU *has* 64-bit support (since around 2003, all of them have).

Your question implicitly states that you want to run the 64-bit app in your own system environment. If it is really your intention, this excludes all virtual machine-based solutions. The only remaining which is known for me is the kernel-emulation of the qemu. So:

```
qemu-x86_64 ./your_64bit_app
```

It runs your app *on your current system, with your current kernel, with your current environment variables*. Of course it is not very fast, it has to emulate your cpu.

It can emulate only linux x86-64 apps.

Comment: Somewhere I've also read, as if also vmware could do that, but this is not enough sure info for an answer. Afaik recent vmware are 64bit-only on the host side.

Answer (score 1):

Most 64-bit architectures are extensions to the 32-bit ones. They're newer and completely different so obviously a 32-bit architecture has no idea what the 64-bit counterpart is. They don't know what the new features are, what new registers there are... Even if they know, they have no access to the new registers and features. As a result a 32-bit kernel can't save 64-bit contexts. All of that makes running 64-bit apps on a 32-bit system impossible.

A carefully crafted 64-bit-aware 32-bit kernel [can run 64-bit apps](https://superuser.com/q/340549/241386) but it still needs some 64-bit code to do the context savings, which makes it not a pure 32-bit kernel anymore.

You can run a 64-bit OS inside an emulator, or a 64-bit guest virtual machine inside 32-bit host with VT-x. But technically you're running in a different 64-bit system. It's still not possible to run 64-bit code directly on 32-bit Linux kernel