# Satisfying lib dependency

Tags: linux-mint, libraries, shared-library

I have a program (which I will call `foo` here) compiled for x64 (my current arch).  When I try to run it, it goes:

```
./foo: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Relevant part of `locate` output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.1.3
```

Looking around, I found the question [Mint: correct way to install /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119798/mint-correct-way-to-install-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libgmp-so-3), whose author says: "I have a 32-bit binary that needs `libgmp.so.3` on an x86_64 installation."  In that thread, they suggest installing the compiled for 32-bit version Ubuntu package, which I did, only to add `/usr/lib/libgmp.so.3` and `/usr/lib/libgmp.so.3.5.2` to `locate libgmp` and (as should be expected) change the error to

```
./foo: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

So I wrote the binary author, who very helpfully recompiled, but wrote me back saying the library is now 140 MB, so best option is I recompile myself.

Why isn't the binary dependency on `libgmp.so.3` satisfied by `libgmp.so.10`?

Does this mean the software depends on a certain library version only? Couldn't this be "soft-coded"?

Does a shared library always break backwards compatibility with its previous version (I thought it didn't)?

My options as I perceive them are:

a. Downloading and compiling `libgmp.so.3` for x64

b. Recompiling the software

c. Running risks: Would I be able to write a link to use `libgmp.so.10` (as it were `libgmp.so.3`)?

Would them work? What would be pros/cons?

PS:

extra: ldd for the bin

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff290fa000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8061064000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8060e46000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8060b3f000)
libbz2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f806092f000)
llibz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8060716000)
libgmp.so.3 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8060350000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f80612a0000)
```

Comment: @G-Man thank you so much for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

From your ldd output, it doesn't look like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is in the path that `ld` knows to search for shared libraries. You can check this by running `ldconfig -v` with superuser privileges, which will spit out a list of all the shared libraries LD can find. If you can't find libgmp in that list, you need to edit your `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/[your-system-arch].conf` to put `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` in the library search path.