# Failed installation 32-bit python on 64-bit Linux Mint

Tags: debian, linux-mint, python, 64bit, 32bit

I basically have two questions:

1. How do you install 32-bit Python alongside 64-bit Python on linux?
2. How do I fix my broken system from the failed attempt below?

I just tried to install a 32-bit python alongside my 64-bit python on Linux Mint 16. It's not as straight forward as I hoped for (something like `sudo apt-get install python32` would be nice) but after a bit of googling I downloaded Python 2.7.6 and did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs gcc-multilib checkinstall
CC="gcc -m32" LDFLAGS="-L/lib32 -L/usr/lib32 -Lpwd/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib32" ./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32
make
sudo checkinstall
```

The should supposedly make me able to run 32-bit or 64-bit (default) like this:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
/opt/pym32/bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
```

... but `/opt/pym32/` wasn't even created. Worse, my system now reports 29 broken dependencies, indicating that the new python replaced the old one or something like that. To fix it, aptitude suggests that I remove a whole bunch of packages that I need and install a whole bunch of packages that I don't need.

I used checkinstall rather than `make install` to be able to reverse/uninstall if something went wrong, but uninstalling/reinstalling python won't work because of the broken dependencies. Is there a way to get out of this mess?

Comment: What's the content of the package created by `checkinstall`? And post a complete transcript of the `apt-get` calls that resulted in dependency errors.

Comment: As an alternate, simpler approach, I suggest [setting up a 32-bit installation in a chroot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu).

Comment: Basic question is why you need 32bit python ? Python programs are architecture agnostic so there isn't real reason for 32bit python in 64bit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 32-bit packages on 64-bit platform

First of all you need to allow your package manager to install packages with different architecture. But who is who? Apt is simple combination of `wget` and `dpkg`. The real package manager is `dpkg`, which provides low-level infrastructure for handling operations with real `*.deb` packages.

So, lets see available architectures for our particular case:

```
dpkg-architecture --list-known | grep -E "amd64|i386"
```

or

```
dpkg-architecture --list-known | ack "amd64|i386"
```

As you can see, in our case architectures are `amd64` and `i386`. Now you can allow package manager to install `i386` packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Now you can install your packages:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install python2.7:i386
```

Typically, first `i386` package install results in installing a lot of dependency-packages. For example, on my **Debian x86_64 GNU/Linux testing (stretch)** installing `skype` (which depends on `libc6:i386`) results in installing **189** packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | ack i386 -c
```

The problem is that `python2.7:i386` conflicts with `python2.7` and a lot of packages depends on `python2.7`. So, you wont be able to install `python2.7:i386` without removing all graphical environment.

### Fix broken dependencies

This is simple one:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```