# How do I set up a .deb file?

Tags: download, application, deb

I am trying to set up a .deb package I have downloaded. I need to know how to set it up. I do have root privileges, and I am currently running BasilOS Linux(Trinity).

Comment: Is BasilOS a Linux distribution? Is it a Debian derivative?

Comment: Yes, it is based off of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

To install a package which you have in the form of a `.deb` file, use the [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html) command as root:

```
dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb
```

`dpkg` is a low-level package manager. It doesn't understand dependencies. If the installation command complains of missing dependencies, install them first. If the dependencies are available in your distribution, you can use `apt-get install` to install them. For example, if `dpkg -i` complains

> ```
> somepackage depends on someotherpackage; however:
>  Package someotherpackage is not installed.
> ```

then try (as root)

```
apt-get install someotherpackage
```

Note that packages intended for one version of a distribution might not always work in another version because they require different versions of libraries. Don't try to force broken dependencies: APT doesn't cope well with them. The best thing to do if you're faced with unsatisfiable dependencies depends on the circumstances. Sometimes you can install other packages that aren't from your distribution. Sometimes you can recompile the package from source and link with other dependencies. Sometimes you can [install another distribution in a chroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/12957#12957).

Answer (score 0):

First, type `root` to gain root accesses. Then, once you are in the same directory the .deb file is, type `getdeb packagename.deb` to install and setup the package in question. I have only tried this as root, I am not sure it will work if you do not have lower privileges.

Comment: Yes, I believe that the getdeb command is based off of dpkg and (specifically about BasilOS), the newer versions of BasilOS Linux have apt-get installed although Trinity and Duo only have dpkg and getdeb...