# Install newer & older versions of python on debian?

Tags: debian, python

How can I install extra versions of python on Debian (jessie). On Ubuntu I can use the "deadsnakes" PPA which will give me any python version I want, with the version name in the command (e.g. `python33` for python 3.3). This allows me to install them all beside each other. I can use virtualenvs to install specific python packages for specific versions without messing with the system packages. I maintain some python libraries, and they need to work on many versions of python. If I have the python binary installed, then tox will take care of using virtualenvs for each python version.

So what's the debian equivalent of Ubuntu's deadsnakes PPA?

**UPDATE** I want to install python: 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: Can you specify which versions of Python you want installed? I think Jessie has a few different versions available.

Comment: In my opinion you are probably better off just installing various Python versions from source.

Answer (score 15):

**I would say there is no Debian equivalent to Ubuntu's deadsnakes PPA**

Under Debian, using Ubuntu packages or repositories is not recommended. As this post appears in search engines, I propose here an answer that is less dangerous for a Debian system.

Installing Python manually is possible. As an example, you can use the following instructions to install 3.5.2 version

**Prerequisites**

Install dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
```

**Building Python**

You can build Python in a specific folder using the `--prefix` parameter from `configure` command:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz
tar zxf Python-3.5.2.tgz
cd Python-3.5.2/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Instead of `/usr/local`, one can use another base directory. As an example:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/python-3.5.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/python-3.5.2
```

**Selecting python version**

Using PATH environment variable can help choosing the right python version to use. But one can also use symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/python-3.5.2/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /opt/python-3.5.2/bin/pip3.5 /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Using `-f` option will allow you to replace existing symlinks

---

**Note:** For python 3.9.16 (possibly any `+3.9` version) you also might need to install the library: `libffi-dev` so the dependencies would be:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 14):

### Using the PPA

You can use the PPA on Debian. Pick an [Ubuntu version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) that's from slightly before your Debian version, and it should have all the necessary libraries. For wheezy, the oneiric PPA seems ok (but it lacks more recent Python versions). For jessie, the trusty PPA should work.

To add a PPA on Debian,

1. Download and add the [PPA signing key](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0xF23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776&fingerprint=on&op=index) with:

   ```
   gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776
   gpg --export F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776 | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/ppa-deadsnakes.gpg > /dev/null
   ```
2. Then create a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa-deadsnakes.list` containing:

   ```
   deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa-deadsnakes.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty main 
   deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa-deadsnakes.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty main
   ```
3. Finally run `apt-get update` and install the desired packages.

If you can't get the PPA working for some reasons (maybe you can't find a version that works with the libraries you have), you can download the source and recompile them for your distribution.

### Using a chrooted system

What I usually do to test compatibility with other versions is to run older or newer distributions in a [chrooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) system. For example, you could install various versions of Ubuntu with the Python versions you're interested in, or you could install trusty in a chroot and install the PPA there. For more information, see [my schroot guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/12957#12957).

Comment: You should avoid using Ubuntu PPAs on Debian, as it might cause issues or other conflicts.  (It's also possible to use `pyenv` virtualenvironments for multiple Python versions)

Comment: I can confirm that I have successfully installed **python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5 and 3.6** on current **debian testing** using this approach. The only caveat I came across was that I needed to dig up an old version of `libssl1.0.0` which I found here: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0 . I also used the *xenial*  (16.04) versions of packages (current lts), though I believe trusty still works.