# How do I install udeb packages in Debian?

Tags: debian, docker, debconf

I want to try installing [`cdebconf-udeb`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/cdebconf-udeb) in a Debian Buster Docker container, however `apt search cdebconf-udeb` turns up empty. How could I try to install this package if I really wanted to.

#### Context

I'm building a Docker image. One of my dependencies is [`tzdata`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/tzdata) which itself is dependent on [`debconf-2.0`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/debconf-2.0) (or `debconf`).

Now [`debconf-2.0`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/debconf-2.0) can be provided by `cdebconf`, `debconf`, or `cdebconf-udeb`. Both `cdebconf` and `debconf` have a (recursive) depencency on `perl-base`. I want to minimize the size of my container and get rid of the Perl dependency. I thought I could try this by installing `cdebconf-udeb`, which doesn't have the Perl dependency and would still provide `debconf-2.0`. However, it seems I can't find the package in aptitude.

I do know that `cdebconf-udeb` is intended for the use in building debian-installer images only, and is not intended for a normal Debian system. However I still wanted to try if I could use it to minimize my Docker image.

Could I install [`cdebconf-udeb`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/cdebconf-udeb) to minimize my Docker container?

I'm aware of [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410137/447861), however It was suggested to me in the comments to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting approach to reducing container sizes! And any associated danger will be limited to the generated container image...

`apt` & co. don’t know how to handle micro-`deb`s, so you’ll need to do their work yourself. For `cdebconf-udeb`, that means downloading its `udeb`, as appropriate for your target architecture(s), along with those for `libc6-udeb`, `libdebian-installer4-udeb`, and `libtextwrap1-udeb`. You can then install all those with `dpkg -i`. Because micro-`deb`s don’t use multiarch, the libraries don’t conflict with their “big brothers”.

You *will* end up with duplicate libraries in some cases, and I’m not sure the micro-`deb` variants include all the features supported by the standard variants, so you might run into issues down the line. The same goes for anything relying on the essential packages you’ll end up forgoing, such as `perl-base` (packages aren’t supposed to declare their dependencies on essential packages, unless they need a versioned dependency; any package is allowed to assume that all essential packages are installed).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stephen's answer I tried to following:

```
# docker build --tag udeb-experiment --file ./Dockerfile .
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --quiet --yes --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
    && apt-get clean \
    && mkdir /tmp/debs \
    && cd /tmp/debs \
    && wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-udeb_2.28-10_amd64.udeb \
    && wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cdebconf/cdebconf-udeb_0.249_amd64.udeb \
    && wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libd/libdebian-installer/libdebian-installer4-udeb_0.119_amd64.udeb \
    && wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libt/libtextwrap/libtextwrap1-udeb_0.1-14.2_amd64.udeb \
    && dpkg -i --force overwrite ./*.udeb \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove --yes --allow-remove-essential \
        wget \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm --recursive --force /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/debs
```

This overwrites some of the libraries with the udebs. However, this does not reduce size nor does get rid of the perl dependency. Apt still lists `debconf` and its depencencies installed. Additionally this led to problems downstream with some other packages I wanted to install.