# How to install python2.7-dev package on vanilla debian 12?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I searched in my repo but couldn't find the "python2.7-dev" to install some previously built old packages by building and installing from GitHub repo. Is there a way to sideload it?

Answer (score 2):

You can still install Python 2.7 from Debian 11. Mixing releases is typically decried as a bad idea, but that is mostly in the context of adding a newer release; adding an older (still-supported) release is much less error-prone, as long as you keep an eye on any packages `apt` wants to remove.

Add a file, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye.list`, containing

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main
```

Run `sudo apt update`, and you will be able to install `python2.7-dev`.

As you are probably aware, maintaining Python 2-based projects is becoming increasingly difficult, and the above won’t be a viable approach once Debian 11 is no longer supported (some would argue it already isn’t viable).

Answer (score 0):

### The PPA Approach

While Stephen's answer is certainly viable until Bullseye is no longer supported. I believe this approach will survive until the various python versions are removed from the PPA.  Adding this PPA or *Personal Package Archive*, or any for that matter is relatively easy.

### The PPA Specifically for Python

The [Dead Snakes Personal Package Archive](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) contains packaged versions of Python all the way back to 2.3. Add it with: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Note that these are made to work with Ubuntu, and since that's a Debian derivative:

> The packages may also work on other versions of Ubuntu or Debian, but that is not tested or supported.

See also: [Install newer & older versions of python on debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188741/install-newer-older-versions-of-python-on-debian).  Read Gilles' answer from 8 years ago that's still quite valid.