# how to get 32 bit kernel headers in 64 bit debian installation

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, 64bit, 32bit

```
aptitude search linux-headers
```

provides this:

```
p   linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all      - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-pack
p   linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-amd6 - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-pack
i   linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64    - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64     
i A linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common   - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-4    
p   linux-headers-amd64             - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration
```

but i need to get 32 bit kernel headers

how to do that with apt?

Comment: This is probably a dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/4671. Voting to close as dupe.

Comment: I think it is not duplicate because it is easy way just to get a package without creating schroot envieronment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It required to modify /etc/apt/sources.list 
adding i386 to downloadable architectures like that:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

After that you need to make

```
apt-get update
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

and to install package for i386 architecture:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae:i386
```

Comment: Modifying the sources.list is not necessary.

Comment: Especially not with a Quantal source on a Jessie system!