# Setting up a dev environment for different distro than one installed

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, packaging, development

I am looking to be able to set up a development environment.

Here's the deal, I prefer to run arch as my operating system but I also maintain packages for an ubuntu based distro and I was wondering if there was a way to set up an environment from within arch to accomplish this.  I would like to do it without dual booting and without the need for virtualbox.

Is this possible?  Is it something I can possibly use a local docker instance for?  A minimal chroot?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Arch you can use [`debootstrap`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/debootstrap/) to set up Debian or Ubuntu chroots. It's as easy as

```
debootstrap jessie ./jessie-chroot http://httpredir.debian.org/debian
```

(to set up a Jessie chroot; Ubuntu variants are similar).

You can also deploy the [Open Build Service](http://openbuildservice.org/) locally and use that to build for all the main distributions. That's a bit more complicated though...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I haven't responded yet, i've been quite busy.  I'm still reading up on this and other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Use [schroot](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=schroot) to run the other distribution in a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). A chroot lets you run programs with the paths that they expect, on the kernel that you're already running. The schroot program helps set up a chroot which is created on demand and has access to home directories, `/proc`, etc. Running other distributions or other distribution versions is what it's for.

To install Ubuntu or other Debian-based distributions in a chroot, use [debootstrap](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/debootstrap/).

For more details, see [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu) which is also largely applicable when the host is another Linux distribution.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, i'll read up on it and give it a go.