# How to detect the architecture of the chroot from inside the chroot?

Tags: shell-script, chroot, x86, amd

Let's say for example the host system is running Debian amd64. And on that system, another Debian i386 has been installed inside a folder using debootstrap. Then assume a shell script is running inside the chroot.

From inside the chroot, dpkg-architecture / uname -a show only what architecture the host system has (amd64).

How do I detect the [package] architecture of the chroot? (i386)

Answer (score 5):

`dpkg-architecture` and `dpkg --print-architecture` work for me.

```
/root# chroot /f/32
{3}/# uname -m
x86_64
{3}/# file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=152184668fe2d58ef2ef49e8c40d044880f8e318, stripped
{3}/# dpkg --print-architecture
i386
{3}/# dpkg-architecture
DEB_BUILD_ARCH=i386
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=32
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=i386
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=i586
DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i586-linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=i386-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_ARCH=i386
DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32
DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=i386
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=i586
DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=i586-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=i386-linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_ARCH=i386
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_BITS=32
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_CPU=i386
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_TARGET_GNU_CPU=i586
DEB_TARGET_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_GNU_TYPE=i586-linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_MULTIARCH=i386-linux-gnu
```

That being said, you should probably make programs in the chroot think they're running on a 32-bit system. You can do that by running them with the right [personality](http://linux.die.net/man/2/personality). The [`setarch`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setarch) utility (part of `util-linux`) does that, or simply

```
linux32 chroot /path/to/chroot
```

If you [set up your chroot with schroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/12957#12957), declaring the personality as `linux32` in the chroot definition takes care of that.