# Can apt_preferences track the priority of a package?

Tags: apt

When I run `apt show foo` I see in the output a line that says "Priority:" and one of the values:

- required
- important
- standard
- optional
- extra

Can I use the `apt_preferences` file to filter packages based on this value? For example, I would like to install "required", "important", and "standard" packages from debian stable, but "optional" and "extra" packages from testing.

Answer (score 0):

No, `apt_preferences` doesn't permit filtering by package priority, only by name, version and origin (for several meanings of origin).

Mixing Debian releases wouldn't work anyway, because of dependencies. Many optional/extra packages in testing require more recent versions of required/important/standard packages than the ones in stable.

If you want to have a stable system and to be able to use some programs from testing, install stable and set up a schroot environment with testing. See [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu)