# How to install APT/dpkg on any Linux that doesn't have it?

Tags: package-management, gui, coreos

First I'm gonna confess that I'm quite new to the world of Linux and only used Ubuntu/LinuxMint/Debian.

I just came across a Linux distro called "Core Linux", which is only 11mb in size. Naturally, it doesn't have any GUI, Window/Login managers nor any Desktop environment.

I've tried to install GDK/Gnome3 on it, but since it doesn't have `apt` or `dpkg`, I'm stuck here. *rpm* works though.

So, can anybody give me a way how I can proceed from here? How can I install some of the following?

- `apt`
- `dpkg`
- window manager
- login manager
- desktop environment

Comment: Isn't the distribution called Tiny Core Linux? I haven't used it, but I as far as I know it doesn't have the package management tools you are used to (apt/dpkg). Please have a look at their documentation : http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:getting_started .

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's not what you want.  If a distribution doesn't use the `apt`/`dpkg` format for its packages and repositories, installing the tool itself wouldn't help you much.

If “CoreLinux” is an RPM based distribution, you could look for tools like dnf `and`/or `yum`, which normally are the corresponding tools on RPM based distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a choice of the package manager. Generally speaking, each distribution only supports one low-level package manager, e.g. `dpkg` with the deb package format on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/…, `rpm` with the RPM package format on Fedora/RHEL/SuSE/…, etc. For the most part each distribution has a single high-level package manager framework (APT on Debian, dnf on newer Fedora/RHEL, yum on older Fedora/RHEL, etc.) although occasionally you get a choice there.

If you have to use an unfamiliar package manager, the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) can be useful.

You can use [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) to install Debian packages in a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). You can do this on any system with a Linux kernel, even Android. The Debian packages are installed in a separate hierarchy, not mixed with your existing operating system. [Schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) automates most of the configuration. See [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot) or [my tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/12957#12957) for examples of schroot setup; they're for Debian/Ubuntu on top of Debian/Ubuntu but once you've installed schroot and debootstrap the setup is the same.

As schaiba remarked, “Core Linux” is probably actually [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/). It has its own package manager: [Appbrowser](http://tinycorelinux.net/download_howto.html), with an [extensive available package list](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html) despite the small size of the basic installation. So you probably want to install the Tiny Core packages, not install APT.