# How to install the latest version of gcc and boost on an old version of openSUSE?

Tags: package-management, gcc, suse, boost

I need to install gcc 5.2 and boost 1.62 on openSUSE 11.4. The point is that the official version of these two tools on openSUSE 11.4 is gcc 4.5 and boost 1.44. I tried to build them from source code, but the problem is that regarding to lots of dependencies, I should build those dependencies as well.

Is there any straightforward method to do this job?

Comment: you don't want this ... openSUSE 11.4 is out of support for years.

Comment: @mimi.vx It is still supported.

Comment: openSUSE 11.4 is out of support for years Supported openSUSE is now : openSUSE Tumbleweed and openSUSE Leap 42.1 / 42.2

Comment: @mimi.vx You are right :) I confused openSUSE 11.4 with Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11.4 that is supported currently.

Comment: but still this ins't good idea. This packages are core, and update or multiple install is nontrivial. What I recommend is SLES12SP2 + SDK + Toolchain module

Comment: @mimi.vx Yeah, you are right, but the point is that SLES 11.4 is still working on some HPC clusters around the world.

Comment: in this case : https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/devel:gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you can recompile everything with supported version dependencies. However this can involve a lot of grunt work and the fastest way to get things working is to get someone else to do the grunt work for you. So, in addition to your normal system, install one or more distribution for development work. This doesn't have to have a lot of overhead: you don't need to set up a virtual machine, a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environment will do fine. [Schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) is a handy tool to set up chroot environments with a different system but the same home directory.

I've written a [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu) for Debian-like distributions; you could follow this guide and install Debian unstable on SuSE, and [this blog post by masterpatricko](http://masterpatricko.blogspot.fr/2011/04/development-and-build-environments_20.html) describes) explains a setup with a SuSE host.

For more fine-grained control of development tool versions, you could use [the Nix package manager to install software in your home directory](https://nixos.org/wiki/How_to_install_nix_in_home_(on_another_distribution)). [Nix-user-chroot](https://github.com/lethalman/nix-user-chroot) is a tool similar to schroot that lets you easily run software from a different (Nix-managed, in this case) installation.