# Install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of libgoogle-perftools-dev

Tags: debian, software-installation, libraries, 64bit, 32bit

I am on Debian Stretch and need [google-perftools](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/google-perftools) to profile some programs of mine. My machine is 64-bit; I build the programs for both 64 and 32-bit (using `gcc -m32`). I want to be able to profile both. I already have `libgoogle-perftools-dev` installed. When I now try to add the x86 variant, `apt` wants to remove the x64 variant (see below). Is it possible to install the two variants alongside each other?

```
$ sudo apt install libgoogle-perftools-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0 libboost-regex1.62.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libstemmer0d
  libunwind-dev libunwind8 libunwind8-dev libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgoogle-perftools4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-perftools libgoogle-perftools-dev libgoogle-perftools4 libtcmalloc-minimal4 mongodb mongodb-clients
  mongodb-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgoogle-perftools-dev:i386 libgoogle-perftools4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can bypass the multiarch limitations and [use a 32-bit chroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various `google-perftools` packages don’t have the necessary `Multi-Arch:` declarations in [their control file](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/google-perftools/blob/401a1806332ddd1a13533c40ea7bfdb3a19fc780/debian/control), so no, it isn’t possible to install the `i386` and `amd64` packages in parallel (short of force-installing them, which will cause `apt` to complain a lot and prevent installing or upgrading any other package).

You might want to file a bug asking for this to be enabled. To do so, run `reportbug libgoogle-perftools-dev` and follow the prompts.

See [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/86440) for other ways to run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit system (as suggested by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)).

Comment: The maintainers have resolved [the bug I reported](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893928). Thanks again for your help.