# 32 bit apache on a 64 bit linux system

Tags: apache-httpd, 64bit, 32bit

I am just curious: Are there any 64 bit Linux systems, which support a 32 bit version of Apache? As far as I know, a 64 bit Linux system supports only an Apache 64 bit and a 32 bit Linux system supports only an Apache 32 bit.

**Edit**

My motivation was just to know, if and which Linux distribution also provide 32 bit packages for applications and / or libraries.

Comment: Just curious as to what motivates you to have a 32 bit app under a 64 bit OS. What is your concern?

Comment: I think his/her motivation is just to know if it works, since on the question he uses "as fas as i know, a 64 bit Linux system supports only an Apache 64 bit..."

Comment: Define "support". Do you want to know if it will run? If the distro provides a straightforward way of installing it? If they will accept bug reports for that configuration? If they will provide you commercial support if you run it and it breaks?

Comment: This question isn’t Debian-specific...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many distributions support this, in various ways.

On Debian and derivatives, you’d install using the `amd64` architecture for the system (or even just the kernel), then add the `i386` architecture (`dpkg --add-architecture i386` followed by `apt update`) and install `apache2:i386`. See [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/86440) for details.

On Fedora, you can install `httpd.i686` directly on a 64-bit x86 system.

Other distributions have different ways to support this, the above isn’t exhaustive.

Comment: On Debian `dpkg --add-architecture i386` to enable 32bit software to be installed . On Fedora you just need to install the package with the  `.i686` sufix as you said (`yum install httpd.i686`)