# Running x86_64 binaries on arm64

Tags: linux, qemu, glibc, arm64

I have been searching for a simple way to run x86_64 binaries on arm64 GNU/Linux.

I've tried qemu-user:
`qemu-x86-64 -L /usr/x86-64-linux-gnu /opt/x86_64program`, but I'm getting
`/lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.32' not found`, so I went ahead and tried compiling and installing it from source ... no success, still getting the error.

So I tried to build the binary from source (it's written in Rust) using Cargo with the target param set to `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` ... after compiling most of the components, it throws and error saying that it `had to abort due to previous error`, which seems to have something to do with wrong libs (in `/usr/bin/ld`).

At this point, I've given up hope on getting this to run.

How would you proceed with running x86_64 binaries on arm64?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have already found the answer: use qemu-x86-64. Qemu only emulates the processor, and qemu-user reroutes system calls. You still need to install a suitable version of libraries. Presumably the glibc version under `/usr/x86-64-linux-gnu` is older than 2.32.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' apt says it's the latest version

Comment: It's the version from your distribution. Apparently the binary you have was built against a more recent version. It's easy to install a more recent debian/ubuntu in a schroot, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/12957#12957

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Ah, yeah, I was looking for something like `schroot`. I learned from my mistake which I just recovered from, where I stupidly downloaded a libc6 .deb right from Ubuntu repos and run `dpkg -i` on it. Biggest mistake ever XD.