# file not found when executed but exec bit set and accessible by other commands

Tags: linux, bash, debian, permissions, terminal

On my system I'm puzzled by a behaviour I cannot understand: Previously I did install an SDK in my user-local binary path and all the files are there. However bash returns "file not found" when I try to execute it although the execute bit is set. Any hints what could be the cause for this behaviour?

Quote from xterm:

```
~/bin$ ls -l powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++
-r-xr-xr-x 2 planetmaker planetmaker 851784  1. Mär 2018  powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++
~/bin$ ./powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++
bash: ./powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++: File or directory not found
~/bin$ file ./powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++
./powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=e28aa4bde5334a2e89f694c75f804fc6fe576f58, stripped
```

Comment: Is the executable for the correct architecture?

Comment: Please use `LC_ALL=C` to show errors in English. Here, you can run `LC_ALL=C ./powerpc-604-linux-gnu-g++` and then edit your question to show us the message.

Comment: It took me asking this question here to realize that. No, it wasn't the right architecture :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the architecture. My system is a 64-bit system, yet the SDK is a 32-bit system. Debian allows multi-arch support (e.g. this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/47003#47003)). After installing 32-bit support, the binaries work as expected.