# Install single debian experimental packages?

Tags: debian, apt, glibc

I'm continually getting this error:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

What I did before was add the Debian experimental repo and update to 2.17. But through a long chain of events, this ended up breaking almost everything on my system, and I had to reinstall. Is there any way to upgrade just this single package, without screwing up apt?

Comment: Which version do you have installed?

Comment: @terdon Crunchbang 11, which is Debian 7

Comment: I mean which version of libc. It looks like something is searching for 2.14, which one do you have installed? You said you reinstalled so I assume you're not still on 2.17.

Comment: IMO your best option would be to just switch to debian jessie aka testing, and `apt-get install openbox` (and related packages) to keep the same openbox-based UI.  or use xfce. or maybe lxde.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the issue is that you want to install a package from experimental, and this depends on more recent versions of core packages like the C library (`libc6`). The incorrect thing to do it to install a more recent versions of those core package, like the C library. The correct thing to do is to rebuild the package on your system, against the versions of the build dependencies that your system uses, if possible. In some cases this is not so easy, but this really depends on the situation.

Comment: Note that I am inferring this from the question, which is poorly written and unclear (sorry). It is possible the questioner really just wants to upgrade libc6 for some other reason, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @FaheemMitha most of the programs giving me the error about outdated glibc are closed-source

Comment: @tkbx: Ok, I see. In that case, I withdraw my comments above. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading a single package is often not a problem. Upgrading `libc` *will* be. There are simply too many other packages that depend on it:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libc6 |wc
16057
```

That means that 16057 other packages will depend on `libc6` and some of them are bound to have problems with the new version. That's one of the main benefits of a packaging system.

So, you don't want to upgrade that without upgrading the rest of your system. What you *could* do is create a `chroot` environment and install a minimal distribution there. For details on how to do that, have a look at @Gilles's answers here:

- [Installing two glibc alongside in debian/ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/installing-two-glibc-alongside-in-debian-ubuntu)
- [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu/12957#12957)