# How to properly upgrade glibc?

Tags: upgrade, glibc

The firmware of my NAS comes with a rather old version of `glibc`, namely 2.5. In order to cope with some precompiled binaries linked<sup>*</sup> to `glibc` 2.15, I would like to upgrade it. From some simple testing in a `chroot` environment I learned simply adding the newer `libc-2.15.so` and updating the symlink `libc.so.6` will yield an unusable system; probably due to `libc-2.15.so` being linked to `ld-linux.so.3` in turn, which would of course also require the 2.15 version instead of the 2.5 one. But before I descend into too much trial and error,

> what is the correct procedure to manually upgrade glibc?

---

<sup>*</sup>despite being linked "statically", they *still* dynamically link to glibc...

Comment: "In order to cope with some precompiled binaries (despite being linked "statically", they still dynamically link to glibc...) linked to glibc 2.15." Taking out the brackets, this reduces to "In order to cope with some precompiled binaries linked to glibc 2.15.". I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for pointing that out, I never realized I forgot finishing that sentence - hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Yes, it reads better now, though having that embedded bracket does not help with clarity. I assume that rebuilding the firmware with a newer libc is not an option?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Debracketed now. No, the firmware unfortunately contains some proprietary components :/

Comment: Nitpick city. You marking your text with a *, but are using a 1 in your "footnote." Yes, that is (part of why) proprietary sofrware sucks. Look for free third party firmware perhaps? Or develop your own. Easier said than done, granted.

Comment: whoops, fixed within the edit window, thanks

Comment: I recommend to use a chroot-ed environment. Get everything that may be of help to work there; ideally use it statically compiled. Make should be statically compiled. I also recommend getting busybox statically compiled there. Use a recent gcc and make sure that it works fine; perhaps even have multiple gcc variants so that you can fallback. When you are ready to compile glibc, I recommend to test-compile it into another directory and test it first there. In short - try to have a working procedure that is as failsafe proof as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading the standard library is risky, as some programs and libraries may depend on the current version.

My recommendation if you need to run newer programs is to install a full [chrooted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) distribution. This requires more disk space, but is a lot simpler and less risky than trying to update libc. Debian provides a tool to facilitate installations in a chroot: [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). See [Installing two glibc alongside in debian/ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/installing-two-glibc-alongside-in-debian-ubuntu/12566#12566) (a very similar situation) for more explanations and [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu/12957#12957) for a full how-to in a slightly different situation.

Comment: I feared as much... Actually I _am_ currently using a chrooted Gentoo installation. In order to compile out-of-chroot binaries it'd probably be easier to downgrade Gentoo's glibc then, or use a sufficiently old version... Then again I severely doubt (or at least hope not) this is the final answer.

Comment: What do you mean by saying upgrading glibc "is risky"? Glibc is backward compatible, so it should generally work or did I not understand something here?

Comment: @Nils What you're missing is the difference between *should* and *does*. Programs sometimes depend on undocumented behavior that changes between versions.